# MVC 4: Incompatible version DotNetOpenAuth with System.Web.Mvc causes Inheritance security rules violated by type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, mef

I am making a CMS MVC 4 apps that use MEF to load plugin at runtime. But whenever the program calls:

```
DirectoryCatalog dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"));
```

It causes this error on dirCatalog.Parts:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.OutgoingWebResponseActionResult'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

My DotNetOpenAuth.Core version is 4.3.0.0
and DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet version is 4.3.0.0 it is the default version when we created new MVC 4 projects in Visual Studio.

My System.Web.Mvc version is 5.2.3.0.

If I changed my System.Web.Mvc version into 4.0.0.0 in my Web.config, the dirCatalog.Parts does not produce error, but somehow when the code tries to call the controller, it produces this error:

> Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.

I guess that DotNetOpenAuth version is not compatible with my MVC version. Is there a workaround to match this?

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall the System.web.mvc (v5.2.3.0), then i installed

```
Install-Package DotNetOpenAuth.Mvc5
```

This package will force the system to reinstall System.web.mvc 5.0.0.0 so in the end i downgraded my mvc to v5.0.0.0.

After that i change this code in root/web.config:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

into:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

and my root/views/web.config:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

into:

```
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

and

```
<controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
```

into:

```
<controls>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
  </controls>
```

We need to change the root/views/web.config into version 5 because there is no actual System.Web.Mvc version 4.0.0.0 file in the reference package folder. Thats why we need to match the version into the v5 actual System.web.mvc file.

In overall I dont think this is a good fix, but for now this works. The problem caused by DotNetOpenAuth which is not updated to version 5, but our mvc version is 5++.